# Display full records of duplicate entries across multiple columns

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table (customers) that includes fields telephone_1, telephone_2, telephone_3 & telephone_4.

What I need to see is full records of where any telephone numbers are used in other customers - as I believe something has gone wrong with the data somewhere and customer numbers are duplicated into each other!

I have tried the below code, but this doesn't give me what I want as only compares 1/1, 2/2, 3/3 & 4/4. I have an ID field which can be used to differentiate between records.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Customers AS a
 WHERE 1 < (SELECT Count(*)
 FROM Customers AS b
 WHERE a.Telephone_1 = b.Telephone_1
  OR a.Telephone_2 = b.Telephone_2
  OR a.Telephone_3 = b.Telephone_3
  OR a.Telephone_4 = b.Telephone_4
```

Any assistance is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers AS a
WHERE 1 < (
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM Customers AS b
    WHERE a.Telephone_1 IN (b.Telephone_1, b.Telephone_2, b.Telephone_3, b.Telephone_4)
    OR a.Telephone_2 IN (b.Telephone_1, b.Telephone_2, b.Telephone_3, b.Telephone_4)
    OR a.Telephone_3 IN (b.Telephone_1, b.Telephone_2, b.Telephone_3, b.Telephone_4)
    OR a.Telephone_4 IN (b.Telephone_1, b.Telephone_2, b.Telephone_3, b.Telephone_4)
)
```

**========Take 2=======**

Following the comments:

Create a new table with telephone numbers nd customer IDs

```
CREATE TABLE tempTelephoneNos (
    INTEGER customer,
    VARCHAR(32) telephoneNo
);
```

assuming those are the appropriate data types for the customer Id and phone no.

Populate the new table

```
INSERT INTO tempTelephoneNos (customer, telephoneNo)
SELECT customer_id, telephone_1
FROM customers
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_id, telephone_2
FROM customers
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_id, telephone_3
FROM customers
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_id, telephone_4
FROM customers
```

Then you can find out which telephone numbers appear for more than one customer with

```
SELECT customer, telephoneNo
FROM tempTelephoneNos
WHERE 1 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempTelephoneNos GROUP BY telephoneNo)
```

Comment: Awesome - looks like what I need! However, is there a way I can have it exclude duplicates? As a blank telephone_1 will pick up blank t_2 / t_3 / t_4?

Comment: Also, it would be awesome to see the duplicates together? I.E. if three records use the same number, it would show them next to each other?

Comment: Added blank validation as follows:
"...WHERE (a.Telephone_1 <> '' AND a.Telephone_1 IN (b.Telephone_1, b.Telephone_2, b.Telephone_3, b.Telephone_4))..."

Comment: Sorry abt slow response; I've been away from my desk for a while. Good to see you're getting on well with your problem. Please let us know how you eventually solve it, or if you need further assistance.

Comment: No problem! I have run the above (using <>'' to exclude blanks) and return 639 records. However, these are listed in CustomerID order and the duplicates aren't together? Therefore, I can't establish what Customer the number is duplicated with?

Comment: Thanks for the update! However, when trying to populate the table, I'm getting "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'."

Comment: I had an extra `UNION ALL` at the end of the qury to populate the table. I've removed it now - can you do likewise?